# Excel VBA, Verify if field is greater then zero and add this row to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets, the first I have the fields:

**Sheet01**

```
Code | Description    | Amount |
0f15 | Description 01 | 05     |
0f04 | Description 02 | 00     |
0rt7 | 03 Description |        |
0rt7 | Description 04 | 07     |
```

What I need is that when the user enters an amount greater than 00 (1,2,3,4,5 ...) in the amount, the entire row is inserted into another worksheet that did contain the same fields, but if the quantity is zero (0) or empty, not added to another worksheet starting line for the next turn.

**Sheet02**

```
Code | Description    | Amount |
0f15 | Description 01 | 05     |
0rt7 | Description 04 | 07     |
```

---

[image: Example Imagem]

Hello guys, thanks for the replies, however I could not apply any of them. I'll try to explain better:

When a non-zero value (and different from empty space) is entered in column H of Sheet1 the entire line that contains this value should be copied to Sheet2 in the appropriate cells, something like an invoice where products are added cases the amount thereof are nonzero. I know this is possible just do not know how to do because I am a layman in VBA. If someone can help me I appreciate it.

Comment: +1 for an interesting subject BUT....here comes the overused comment....please can you display the code (this is a coding site) that you have already tried? If you have not tried anything then try using one of the worksheet event procedures and then post your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in the first sheet _Change event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  On Error Resume Next
  If Target.Column <> 3 Or Target.Value = 0 Or Target.Value = "" Then
      Exit Sub
  End If
  Dim sht1 As Worksheet
  Dim sht2 As Worksheet
  Set sht1 = ActiveSheet
  Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
  Target.EntireRow.Copy
  Dim iRow As Integer
  Dim rng As Range
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  sht2.Activate
  iRow = sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  Set rng = sht2.Range("A" & iRow)
  rng.Select
  sht2.Paste
  sht1.Activate
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```